# Selectivity. Приоритет правил css: два класса на одном уровне или один плюс родительский

Tags: css

Не могу разобраться, почему первый css (с одним классом своим и одним родительским) получает больший приоритет, чем второй (с двумя классами на одном уровне)?
Не нахожу в документации про selectivity ничего про то, что наличие родительского класса даёт преимущество.

```
.tableContainerBoxed .background-inherit {
    background-color: red;
}

.dataGridCell.background-inherit {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно почему у вас проблемы. В данном случае селекторы имеют одинаковый вес и по каскадности применяется последнее правило. Ищите ошибку в своём коде. Может в наименовании селекторов. У меня когда-то было, что вместо латинской буквы "C" была русская "С". С виду одно и тоже, но это ошибка

```css
.tableContainerBoxed .background-inherit {
  background-color: red;
}

.dataGridCell.background-inherit {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableContainerBoxed">
  <p class="dataGridCell background-inherit">Hello, world!</p>
</div>
```